# Why we can't create a new instance of State in a view in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui

So in the following code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
@State private var blurAmount = 0.0 {
    didSet {
        print("Hey")
    }
}

init() {
    _blurAmount = State(wrappedValue: 3.3)
}
var body: some View {
    Button("Tap me") {
        
        // this line gives an error saying Cannot assign to property: 'self' is immutable
        _blurAmount = State(wrappedValue: 3.3)
    }
}
```

}

I know that `_blurAmount` is the `State<Double>` struct itself and `_blurAmount = State(wrappedValue: 3.3)` is creating a new instance of Struct. And normally would be used in init().

Expected result I wanted is it printing "Hey" whenever I tap the button. So that I can actually conform `_blurAmount = State(wrappedValue: 3.3)` creates a new instance of State.

But why we can't create a new instance of Struct in a View?

Comment: Because the whole purpose of `@State` is to persist the data and cause redraws. The OS sets aside memory each time an `@State` variable is initialized. If you could do this, you would cause a memory leak that would crash the app rapidly. And further, you should either set the @State in the header or in the `init()`, but not both. And, preferably in the header. Why do you want to create a new instance instead of simply updating the current one?

Comment: What does "can't create a new instance of Struct in a View" mean? Can you show an example of the code that "can't"?

Comment: @Yrb To confirm that '_blurAmount = State(wrappedValue: 3.3)' actually creates a new instance of State struct, initially I added print("Hey") in the didSet property observer, and tried to see it whether it prints "Hey" whenever I click the Button.

Comment: @matt above code in my question, it works in init(), but doing that inside of Button doesn't work. It gives me an error.

Comment: Please stop being so vague. What does "doesn't work. It gives me an error." mean? Copy the error and paste it into your question.

Comment: @matt just did that, thanks for advice

Comment: And please correct your question. It is starting to look like when you say "we can't create a new instance of Struct" you mean "we can't create a new instance of _State_." Could that be so?

Answer (score 1):

This really has nothing to do with State per se. Let's take a simpler example!

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var greeting = "howdy"
    init() {
        greeting = "hello"
    }
    var body: some View {
        Button("Tap me") {
            greeting = "hey there" // same error
        }
    }
}
```

This is simply how Swift works. ContentView is a struct. A struct is not mutable in place. Thus, you can *initialize* `greeting`, but once initialization is over, you cannot *modify* it, because that would be a mutation of the struct ContentView, and you can't do that.

This principle is in fact one of the key principles of SwiftUI. This is exactly why `@State` exists; a `@State` variable is mutable, because it has (as you have said) a separate existence behind the scenes. The idea here is to force you to express the mutable aspects of your Views in clear and controlled manner.

Having said all that, you *can* assign a value to your actual variable, exactly *because* it is a `@State` variable: you can say `blurAmount = 4.4` (or whatever). This is legal, and it works as you would expect:

```
var body: some View {
    Button("Tap me") {
        blurAmount = 4.4
    }
}
```

Comment: Can I understand in this way? 'The act of changing the memory address of property is not allowed in Struct'. For example changing wrappedValue or projectedValue of State property does not change the memory address of the instance of State. But '_blurAmount = State(wrappedValue: 3.3)' changes memory address of the instance of State, which is  not allowed.  And 'greeting = "hey there"' is also trying to change memory address of the property 'greeting'?. Am I right?